# How to display the salesforce1 search page

Tags: visualforce

I have created a VF page for search my page use to work properly for search. Now I need to use it on my sf1 and result should come like this  [image: Search Result]

Haw can I achieve it. I try from here http://sfdc-styleguide.herokuapp.com/?id=examples but it doesn't work for me. The code I used is

```
   <article class="mam bg-1 border border--3 pam brm ng-isolate-scope" title="United Partners, Inc." detail1="San Francisco, CA" detail2="Enterprise Customer" on-select="selectHandler(event)">
        <h1 class="man f3 text-color-1 fw-semibold ng-binding">
              United Partners, Inc.
        </h1>
    <ul class="list-plain man pan">
       <li class="f5 text-color-2 ng-binding">San Francisco, CA</li>
       <li class="f5 text-color-2 ng-binding">Enterprise Customer</li>
   </ul>
```

my VF page :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>


 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock > 
 <apex:outputPanel id="searchPanalID" rendered="{!if(soqlResult.size == 0 || soqlResult.size == null, true, false)}">
  <h1><apex:outputText value="Survey Result Screen"></apex:outputText></h1><br/><br/>
     <apex:repeat value="{!wcls}" var="sobj"><br/>
         <!--<apex:column >-->
            <label>
               <apex:outputText value="{!sobj.fieldLabel}"></apex:outputText>
               <apex:inputField value="{!sobj.objectName[sobj.fieldname]}" /> 
             </label>
         <!--</apex:column>-->

     </apex:repeat>
      <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchResult}"  />
   </apex:outputPanel>
      <apex:outputPanel id="searchresultID">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!soqlResult}" var="rst" rendered="{!if(soqlResult != null, true, false)}"  >

               <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
                   <apex:outputLink value="/apex/Update_Contact?categoryID={!categoryID}&contactID={!rst.id}" target="_blank" style="color:#0099FF;" >Edit</apex:outputLink> 
               </apex:column>

               <apex:repeat value="{!fieldNameLst}" var="f">
                   <apex:column value="{!rst[f]}"/>
               </apex:repeat>

       </apex:pageBlockTable>
       </apex:outputPanel>
     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Please do help me t get the result for this solution. I just want my search result as shown in above image. For that can anyone guide me what I need to do to achieve it on SF1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Anu, could you explain what you mean by "it doesn't work for me. ", maybe a screenshot of your result may help ?

Comment: I just want my search result as shown in above image. For that can anyone guide me what I need to do to achieve it.